# How to pass a form value from AngularJS to JSP

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I have a form where it has the username and password. Once the user enters, I am able to fetch the values in AngularJS and when I try to redirect to another JSP, how am I supposed to pass these values to the JSP.

I have set the username value in ModelMap.

```
            model.addAttribute("userName", userName);
```

I tried using the below but not sure If it is correct.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="model"> ${model.userName}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to another JSP you can pass the values as request parameters. You would need to create the URL within your angular controller so that you can concatenate the values from the model to form a URL string.